# Please help me verify this statement of sum of polynomials function at each x

Tags: polynomials

I have found an interesting property of polynomial function

When I have multiple of 2nd degree polynomial functions. I could use method of 3 points to solve for $a,b,c$

$$a_nx^2 + b_nx + c_n = p_{nx}$$
$$a_n + b_n + c_n = p_{n1}$$
$$c_n = p_{n0}$$

But then. If I carefully select $n$ number of $p_{nx},p_{n1},p_{n0}$ so that

$$\sum_{i=0}^np_{nx} = \sum_{i=0}^np_{n0} = \sum_{i=0}^np_{n1} = 1$$

It seem like all the point of these polynomial could be sum to 1 for every $x$. Also I think it don't have to be 1, it could be any number just that if the 3 group of points will sum to the same number

For example. I have made these 3 lines. Red Blue and Purple

At $x=0$ is $0,0.4,0.6$

At $x=1$ is all $\frac13$

At $x=\frac12$ is $0,\frac13,\frac23$

The green line is the sum of these function. Which become just linear 1

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/95fpjobdht

[image]

I wonder if these property is also true for all $n$ all $p$ and all degree of polynomial with the same construct?

And if it is true why is that? Can we prove it? Are there any name of this property?

Answer (score 3):

The quadratic polynomials form a three dimensional vector space.  $\{1,x,x^2\}$ forms a basis of that space.  $1$ is a fine quadratic polynomial that is $0x^2+0x+1$ as an element of the vector space.  If you fit a quadratic through three points such that the value of the quadratic is $1$ at all three points you will get the constant $1$ polynomial.  Because $1,x,x^2$ are linearly independent, no other quadratic will go through those three points.

Comment: Is this also true for cubic, quartic and any $n^{th}$ degree of polynomial?

Comment: Yes.  Nothing I said was specific to quadratics except for the dimension of the vector space and the specific basis.